# Replicate Bootstrap Carousel arrows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I saw that [bootstrap 3 carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) arrows are made just using css. I tryed to copy the css code on a diferent project but it doesn't work.

My html file looks like this:

```
<span class="arrow"></span>
```

And my css file looks like this:

```
.arrow:before {
    display: inline-block;      
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    content: "";
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";        
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #000;
}
```

I've also imported the font, but it's not working. Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by `@import` the `bootstrap-glyphicons.css` in your css stylesheet like this:

### JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9soqoxuv/3/)

**HTML:**

```
<span class="arrow"></span>
```

**CSS:**

```
@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc2/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css");

 .arrow {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.arrow:before {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    content:"\e080";
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family:"Glyphicons Halflings";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 48px;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #000;
}
```